# Create a class with classname given as an template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have to create many business objects (Each client should get it's own class). Ideally I would like to be able to access the class by the clients internal tag i.e. `Client::getName(void)`, so I created a macro which achieves this.

```
#define CLIENT_CLASS(classname) \
class classname : public Base \
{ \
public: \
    classname(void); \
    ~classname(void) {}; \
public: \
    static const std::string name; \
    static ClientId ID(void) { return CID_##classname; } \
    static Base *createInstance(void) { return new classname(); } \
private: \
    typedef Base super; \
}
```

Originally I copied this as each class seperately, but naturally I'd like to have something that can be edited if need be. I would have preferred to implement this as a template, but I'm not sure if this is even possible, because I don't see any way to specify the classname in a template and AFAIK you can not define static methods in a template anyway? Or am I wrong and there is indeed a way to convert this into a proper template?

`CLIENT_CLASS_BODY` is another macro which bascially looks like the other one, but contains the definition of the common class body (which could be moved to the template if it is possible to templatize it).

The factory looks like this:

## include

```
namespace va {
    CLIENT_CLASS(client1);
    CLIENT_CLASS(client2);
    ....
}
```

## cpp

```
namespace va {
    CLIENT_CLASS_BODY(client1);
    CLIENT_CLASS_BODY(client2);
    ...
}

#define CREATE_CLIENT(classname) addKey(classname::name, classname::ID(), classname::createInstance())

void ClientFactory::initClientMap(void)
{
    CREATE_CLIENT(va::client1);
    CREATE_CLIENT(va::client2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can define static member functions in a template class.

Comment: C++ conception did not fit to this idea (like Java or C#), dont have a "class object". If You want change FUNCTIONALITY initialise one class with reference (pointer) to distinct "implementation object"

Comment: Your use of `static` methods appears very strange to me. You can invoke them only by giving the class name - and then they return it. What is the point of this? You cannot do polymorphism with `static` methods.

Comment: The use case sounds like a typical templated Factory class.

Comment: I do have a factory, but it's still a lot of typing. That's why I want to use a template, Because for the default configuration I don't want to write/copy the same stuff again and again. The create() method is so I can create a list in the factory by providing another macro that creates the neccessary map entries for the factory. The client code is easier, because it just calls the factory with an Id or a name and gets the appropriate object back.

Comment: Have you considered generating the code from the business data model schema?

Comment: Yes, but then I have to have an external tool, which I try to avoid.

Comment: Just want to check your use case can't be simplified.... why do you need the class name to be different for each class? - when I need a lot of one thing (class) I just make a list/map/vector of these classes and find the one I want using a getId() member function... no static functions required. I don't really understand why you need to name the class differently? ... if each had different functionality then fair enough, but the only difference here seems to the name which you can use your unique id/name passed in to the constructor.... maybe you can clarify a little more?

Comment: This is only part of the requirements. The client class gets more complex and I need a class, because I need to override certain methods specifically for a particular client. For most clients I can get away with a mapentry, which is provided via the factory.

Comment: hmmm....ok, but I don't get what you are saving with your macro approach. If you put all your common code into a base class (constructor takes classname as a param). Your base class has functions like getName() and all your virtual functions. Then one way or another you are going to have to implement/define the specialisations/derived-classes somewhere since they are all going to be different they can't be in the macros, right? (i.e. if you can define it in a macro, I am fairly sure I can make a base-class member-function equivalent). maybe you can post come example specialisation classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With template, it should look like something like:

```
template <ClientId Id, const char* Name>
class TClient : public Base
{
public:
    TClient() {}
    ~TClient() {}
public:
    static const std::string name;
    static ClientId ID() { return Id; }
    static Base *createInstance() { return new TClient(); }
private:
    using super = Base;
};

template<ClientId Id, const char* Name> const std::string TClient<Id, Name>::name = Name;
```

And then

```
static constexpr char Client1Name[] = "Client1";
using Client1 = TClient<1, Client1Name>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3a1cdd19e8c3a23)

In the same way,

```
#define CREATE_CLIENT(classname) addKey(classname::name, classname::ID(), classname::createInstance())
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
void ClientFactory::CreateClient()
{
    addKey(T::name, T::ID(), T::createInstance());
}
```

and then

```
void ClientFactory::initClientMap()
{
    CreateClient<va::client1>();
    CreateClient<va::client2>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Based on the comments above, I changed my design and used only a baseclass now. I dropped the requirement to have a classname per client, because I figured that using the factory is almost identical. However, your solution is quite cool. :) Thx!